# Is there anyway to create a failover mechanism similar to kafka's "consumer group"?

Tags: salesforce, cometd

We are trying to design an architecture where we have multiple instances of the same java service executing in a pool - but we only want ONE of these services in the pool to receive (and process) the message sent from a cometd server (salesforce).

This is analogous to having a "consumer group" in kafka where as long as one consumer receives the message, kafka will not send it to any of the other consumers in that group.

I have been reading about OORT - but that seems to be more aimed at horizontally scaling and NOT failover - which is what we are looking for.

Comment: What do you do if a service receives the message and then immediately crashes?

Comment: @sbordet yes its a fair point - but I would argue that is a concern inherent in a messaging paradigm - do you have a suggestion?My question is focused more on how to handle a "live-live" pool excluding any uncontrollable situations like the one you referenced..

Comment: Without more information about what exactly you want to achieve is difficult to suggest. If you want a more detailed discussion, feel free to open an issue to the CometD project and we can discuss it there. However, a guaranteed once delivery is tricky without a central component that coordinates things. CometD can guarantee server-to-client delivery, so 1 subscriber would be enough - if it fails but it is restarted it will receive the messages eventually. With that in place, it can then redistribute the real work to the service pool via normal broadcast.

Comment: Along the lines of @sbordet's note, our suggestion would be to rethink the goals vs architecture. Exactly-once delivery semantics are hard and most of the time [aren't worth it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292382/streaming-api-message-reliability-and-acknowledgement). This is even tougher in Salesforce world because SF [doesn't support](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292382/streaming-api-message-reliability-and-acknowledgement) CometD's ack extension.